# QT Creator - Como abrir uma janela com os diretórios para o usuario selecionar arquivo de texto ? C++

Tags: c++

Tenho em um código que faz uma listagem de professores com suas devidas graduações que está armazenado com o arquivo txt, fazendo a devida abertura com variável ifstream, utilizando open com o nome do arquivo no disco. Assim chamo o construtor da classe na mainwindow.cpp assim :

```
TP2::ProfessorDAO teste("/Users/eugeniojulio/Documents/2015/PUC_2015/PUC_2015_2/TP2/ArquivoDeDados.csv");
```

logo esse será o parâmetro passado para o open abrir meu arquivo, mas obviamente isto tem de ser feito previamente no código, e eu gostaria de saber a maneira de o usuário , ao clicar em um botão, abrir o diretório para daí o usuário selecionar o arquivo desejado e abrí-lo, caso seja válido.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugeria o uso da classe [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html). Esta classe disponibiliza uma caixa de diálogo que permite ao utilizador escolher um ficheiro ou directoria.

Fica aqui um pequeno exemplo:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFileDialog>

class Window : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void buttonClicked();
private:
    QPushButton *button_;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit_;
};

#include "main.moc"

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) { 
    setFixedSize(100, 50);

    button_ = new QPushButton("Abrir ficheiro", this);
    button_->setGeometry(10, 10, 90, 30);
    button_->setCheckable(true);

    lineEdit_ = new QLineEdit(this);
    lineEdit_->setGeometry (10, 40, 180, 30);

    connect(button_, SIGNAL (clicked(bool)), this, SLOT (buttonClicked()));
}

void Window::buttonClicked() {
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Abrir ficheiro"), "/home/bruno", tr("Text files (*.txt)"));

    lineEdit_->setText(filename);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    Window window;
    window.setFixedSize (200, 80);
    window.show ();

    return app.exec ();
}
```

Neste exemplo, ao clicar no botão "Abrir ficheiro" uma nova janela será mostrada onde o utilizador pode seleccionar um ficheiro. O caminho (path) para o ficheiro será depois colocado no LineEdit.